# Limit number of lines read by d3.csv or d3.text

Tags: d3.js

When users of a web app upload a CSV, I want to display on screen a sample of the uploaded data. They could upload 2 to 20 million rows, so I want to limit the number being read by d3 (for speed) and displayed (for style) to, let's say, 100 rows.

Is this possible?

The [documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-request/blob/master/README.md#csv) didn't make the answer apparent to me. I see that it says

> An optional row conversion function may be specified to map and filter
>   row objects to a more-specific representation;

But I don't really understand these row conversion functions or other filters and if they can only be applied after the file is read, or if they can be used to limit the rows being read.

Answer (score 0):

In your row (or accessor) function, use the index (the second argument) to limit the number of rows:

> If a row conversion function is specified, the specified function is invoked for each row, being passed an object representing the current row (d), **the index (i)** starting at zero for the first non-header row, and the array of column names. (emphasis mine)

For instance, in the following example, I'm limiting the number of rows to 5, even if the CSV has 10 rows (I'm using a `<pre>` element to simulate the CSV because I can't upload a real CSV using the Stack snippet):

```js
var data = d3.csvParse(d3.select("#csv").text(), row);

function row(d, i) {
  if (i < 5) return d;
}

console.log("data length is " + data.length);
console.log("data is " + JSON.stringify(data));
```

```css
pre {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<pre id="csv">foo,bar
12,23
13,22
43,66
3,4
66,55
43,48
32,11
11,11
21,23
78,17</pre>
```

Have in mind that if the CSV has in fact 20 million rows, as you said, you'll still have to wait until **all** the file is downloaded. The row function only limits the data array created when you parse the CSV: it will not magically stop the download/parsing process when you get to a certain row.